# setHidden is not working codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I used setHidden(true) and it doesnt work. The container and its components are visible if setHidden is used instead of setVisible. Moreover the problem I am getting while using setVisible is that the background of the container just pop up after the components inside the container animates from top. How can I make the background of the container move frm top along with its components.

```
questionAnswerContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

titleDialog = new Label("Yuppie!");
titleDialog.setUIID("GameDialogLabelBold");
body1 = new Label("Let’s celebrate");
body2 = new Label("with another");
body3 = new Label("drink");
Button ok = new Button(theme.getImage("playIcon.png"));

dialogContainer = (BoxLayout.encloseY(titleDialog, body1, body2, body3, ok));
dialogContainer.getAllStyles().setBgImage(theme.getImage("yuppieDialog.png"));
dialogContainer.setPreferredW(screenWidth * 2 / 3);
dialogContainer.setPreferredH(screenWidth * 2 / 3);

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, LayeredLayout.encloseIn(questionAnswerContainer, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(dialogContainer)));
dialogContainer.getParent().setVisible(false);
//        dialogContainer.setHidden(true);  //it doesnot work, the container and its components are visible if setHidden is used instead of setVisible
f.revalidate();


public void checkIfCorrect(Button checkBtn, Form f) {
    dialogContainer.getParent().setY(-Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight());
    dialogContainer.getParent().setVisible(true);
    //     dialogContainer.getParent().setHidden(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `f.invalidate();` as well.
For me, sometimes combination of both invalidate and revalidate works.

Comment: no it doesnt work. All components of the dialogContainer slides from top to bottom but the bg Img of the dialogContainer just appears, doesnt move from top to its specific position along with its components. I think it caused by using setVisible,isn't it?

Comment: set hidden sets the preferred size to 0 so it requires an `animateLayout` (on the component parent) or `revalidate()` to work. In your case you explicitly set the preferred size ignoring the deprecation warning...

Comment: hello shai.. yeahh that was the reason. But why doesnt the bg image set to the dialogContainer animates from top as the inner components. The bg image jst appears at last after all the animation has taken place.